# Remove Characters from the end of a String Scala

Tags: string, scala

What is the simplest method to remove the last character from the end of a String in Scala?

I find Rubys String class has some very useful methods like *chop*. I would have used "oddoneoutz".headOption in Scala, but it is depreciated. I don't want to get into the overly complex:

```
string.slice(0, string.length - 1)
```

Please someone tell me there is a nice simple method like chop for something this common.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

How about using dropRight, which works in 2.8:-

```
"abc!".dropRight(1)
```

Which produces "abc"

Comment: The most terse I can come up with for 2.7 is "abc!".split(".$)(0)

Comment: Oops I mean      "abc!".split(".$")(0)

Comment: Excellent Thanks Don, I'll have to upgrade to 2.8 :)

Answer (score 13):

```
string.init // padding for the minimum 15 characters
```

Comment: Thanks Walter, that's exactly the method I thought Scala would have. Again all these nice methods are 2.8 only, so upgrade here I come :)

Answer (score 7):

```
val str = "Hello world!"
str take (str.length - 1) mkString
```

Comment: +1, thanks @Daniel Spiewak; led me to "str drop(str.length -4)", gets last 4 of credit card, just what I needed ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want the most efficient solution than just use:

```
str.substring(0, str.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string.reverse.substring(1).reverse
```

That's basically chop, right? If you're longing for a chop method, why not write your own `StringUtils` library and include it in your projects until you find a suitable, more generic replacement?

Hey, look, it's in commons.

[Apache Commons `StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Comment: It sure is Stefan. I was hoping for a method that when you look at the code, you understand what is going on :) What I'm saying is: For something as simple as "remove last character from string" reverse.substring(1).reverse is misleading. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Plus you'd need to wrap the string into a StringBuilder to get a reverse method.

Comment: The first part was mostly a joke :P. Any Java programmer looking at your Scala should be familiar with StringUtils, or at least know of the Apache Commons library to see the import and not be offended. Commons is useful, and it should be used where possible. I've found that most projects include commons at some point, so there's generally no expense to using the library.

You could even alias StringUtils as su in your scala programs and refer to it as su.chop(str), which is pretty succinct and not as sucky as using substring.

Comment: Too bad an implicit for StringUtils would be a lot of work. Just shows the mismatch between the way Scala users and Java users think about extension methods.

Comment: import org.apache.commons.blah.{StringUtils => su} is a lot of work? Ideally, you'd be deploying to an environment with these libraries already established, as I've said.

Comment: I think what Ken meant was that it would be nice if the StringUtils methods were implicitly available on any String instance in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to remove the last character use `.dropRight(1)`. Alternatively, if you want to remove a specific ending character you may want to use a match pattern as

```
val s: String = "hello!"
val sClean: String = s.takeRight(1) match {
    case "!" => s.dropRight(1)
    case _   => s
}
```